# Sharing variables between applescript and bash script in same script

Tags: bash, bash-scripting, applescript, osascript

Is it possible, in a bash script, to have a variable, but also allow applescript (with osascript) to use that variable?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can use bash variables like normal:

```
x=5
osascript -e "display alert \"$x\""
```

Comment: Helped me fix a script that had: `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to display alert "blah blah blah" as critical'`